# Need to access the network folder from the SVN server

Tags: tfs, svn

We  are planning on a daily synchronization between TFS and SVN. The updates (Latest Version) from the TFS will be done to a network folder, and SVN repository will be updated to get the latest from the network folder. Is there a script to access the network folder from the SVN to get the latest?

We were using TFS when the license expired. We have a limited licensing of TFS. So our development is in progress on TFS. But we are eventually planning to move to SVN. We plan move the source code to SVN and do a daily synchronization from TFS to SVN. It will be uni-directional from TFS to SVN. We plan to create a folder in the network which will be updated  with the latest from the TFS db via a script, and another script to run to update the SVN Repository from the network folder containing the 'latest'

Comment: Could you expand on what you're trying to accomplish?  Is this bi-directional?  What's the use case, and the desired goal?

Comment: I need to do a dump from the Network folder to the SVN Repository

Comment: Is this still relevant? Otherwise, you can create a script that just svn commits everything to SVN. Subversion doesn't need a share.